# C# Console.WriteLine has no output for string

Tags: c#, console

I have a class called `Pixel`:

```
class Pixel {   
    public Pixel(int x, int y, string text) {
        int X = x; 
        int Y = y; 
        string Text = text;
    }

    public int X { get; }
    public int Y { get; }
    public string Text { get; }

    public void render() {     
        Console.WriteLine(X);
        Console.WriteLine(Text);
        Console.WriteLine(Y);
    }
}
```

I then create a new instance of pixel with some parameters and try to run the `render()` function:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Pixel pixel = new Pixel(0, 0, "X");
        pixel.render();
    }
}
```

My console output is this:

```
0

0
```

whereas I would clearly expect "X" on line 2. Why does Console.WriteLine not work for `strings`? (I originally tried `char` but I run into the same issue.)

Strangely, if I replace `Console.WriteLine(Text);` with `Console.WriteLine("X")` the issue is fixed. I'm new to C# and don't understand this behaviour. Thanks.

Comment: Your pixels constructor does not update the data members. It should be `X = x` etc., not `int X = x` which is setting a local variable, not the member.

Comment: @wohlstad I'm kicking myself for something so obvious. Thank you!

Comment: Your IDE should be showing warnings about unused local variables. If it doesn't, either configure it or use a better IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Pixel` constructor does not update the data members.
Instead it is setting local variables that do not affect the members.

You should change it to:

```
public Pixel(int x, int y, string text)
{
    X = x;
    Y = y;
    Text = text;
}
```

Then the output will be:

```
0
X
0
```